# Is it "non linearized" or "nonlinearized"?

Tags: grammaticality

As the title says. I am wondering what is grammatically correct .

"non linearized" vs "nonlinearized" (or maybe "non-linearized")

Same for

"non linear" vs "nonlinear" (or maybe "non-linear")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the one nor the other.

Usually, in the words beginning with "non", this one is connected with an hyphen to the main word.

However it is ... non-essential in a mathematical book, just better in a non-technical text.

Comment: -1 I don't even understand this answer - it's not in standard English. I can work out what the first part of the second sentence means, but it should be "Usually, *in words* [no "the"] beginning *with* non, ..."; but I don't understand the second clause: what does "this one" refer to? Do you mean "'non' is followed by a hyphen."? Your third sentence then begins "But ...", suggesting you are about to give some exceptions, but you in fact *illustrate* the use of hyphens. What is the "But" meant to mean.

Comment: @TrevorD You are right, I was writing to hastily ; the text is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

According to a couple of dictionaries, "non" is not an English word but only a prefix. The OED does have it as a word, but not with the meaning apparently intended in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, consult sources/peers in the field in which you are working. The OED lists the main term in question as "non-linear," but if your (reliable) peers disregard the hyphen ("nonlinear"), you should follow their example. I'm sure that the [Journal of Nonlinear Science](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/journal/332) would agree.

In the future, if you need a quick and dirty answer to solve an alternate spelling dispute, you can use the [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams).